# Unable to extend Ubuntu 20.04 partition installed along with Windows 10 using dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I've freed some space on my Windows partition as you in the screen. I've 5 GB of clean unallocated memory that is ready for use. When I try to resize my Ubuntu partition, I've the option to shrink the storage space but not to augment it as you in the second screen. I've browsed through the whole related question but I can't find a clear answer as to why I can't allocate the free space to my Ubuntu partition which is "filesystem Partition 5". I would be really gratefull to anyone who can guide me combine that 5 GB with the memory space initially allocated to Ubuntu.

First image:

[image: First]

Second image:

[image: Second]

Comment: No, He said , he entirely replaced windows with ubuntu, plus he used gparted but according to me lecture partition resizement was made easier since ubuntu 17.00 without using that software, only by freeing space from windows and resize directly using that interface but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do. You can always extend the space at the end but not the other way round. What you're trying to do is to move the start of Partition 5 to another location which is not possible. If you want to, backup your data, re-install using 23+5 = 28GB of space.

Comment: Okey,it seems to be the only option. Can you please clarify what do you mean by  "extend the space at the end" and the other statement please.

Comment: He can do it if he moves Ubuntu partition to the left.  It needs to be done from a live USB.  It is not easy and will probably require reworking grub and fstab to get system working again.  Lost of data is possible without backups.  Your solution is one I would recommend for most cases

Comment: I have no advanced knowledge about grub, fstab.. The only option left is to backup softwares+reinstall or there is an easier way to get it done.

Comment: Even a person who knew what they were doing, would probably go with the reinstall option.  Usually less mistakes and faster.  Double check everything to make sure you are using right partitions and not partitions with Windows or data on them.  I would think about getting an external drive if you are planning to use Ubuntu alot, to give more space.

Comment: With gparted on live installer, it is possible to move a partition left and then expand right. But depending on partition size can take a long time. And any interruption corrupts data. Or good backups required, so you can reinstall if a power failure or other issue in middle of move. https://gparted.org/documentation.php GParted partitioning software - Full tutorial 
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html

Comment: Finally, I reinstalled ubuntu and got enough space memory for further use. thank you all

Comment: I'm late to comment. But as @crip659 pointed out, you can relocate the partition which has it's positives and negatives which you might already have understood. Technically it's possible but you need to weigh the effort and outcome. As I understand now, you already re-installed. Personally I have one more suggestion. 28GB is not enough if you're using Ubuntu/Linux regularly. If you find my answer useful, please upvote and show your love to the community :)